# Is there a name for this common web application architecture?

Tags: architecture, web-development, rest, api

It's an architecture where the client-side consumes data from, and sends data to, a back-end REST API. I would like to learn more about it, but I don't know the name of it.

Comment: Isn't that architecture called *REST*? The API isn't really the back-end, it's how the back-end and the front-end connect to each other. The I in API is for *interface*.

Comment: You might also be thinking of Single-page application, but it's not clear from your question if that's what you mean.

Comment: Search for "client-server architecture" and "RESTful services"

Comment: The name is web application. The web runs on rest. We gave rest a fancy name so other things could run on it too.

Comment: @candied_orange I don't think "Firefox connecting to a static HTML page served by Apache" would generally be considered a "web application"; it is an application of the web, but language doesn't work like that. Similarly, it may be philosophically true that REST is "just" the web, but in practice, people mean something rather more specific.

Comment: @bdsl: No, what the OP is describing isn't REST.  REST might be an architectural style that's used in conjunction with what the OP is describing.

Comment: @IMSoP that’s not what I said. The web runs on REST. That doesn’t mean that REST is just the web. You can run other things on REST. But nothing here tells me it’s another thing.

Comment: @candied_orange REST is the name given by Roy Fielding to the architectural principles which he felt the web **should** follow, and **often** does. It is not, however, an accurate description of how most of the web currently works - in particular [read what Fielding had to say about cookies](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_4_2).

Comment: @bdsl "Single-page application" is what I was thinking of. Thanks.

Comment: @candied_orange "The web runs on rest." That would be a categorical no. Web apps run on a variety of techs. Many Web APIs aren't actually RESTful. Some Apps run a WCF Services. Some on websockets. Some on GraphQL. Some on quite different stuff. Just because you interact via HTTP(S)/Ajax with an API doesn't mean its RESTful.

Comment: @Polygnome I think candied_orange is referring to REST as defined in the Fielding dissertation, not the webservice style.  Literally the dissertation says: "... I then introduce the Representational State Transfer (REST) architectural style and describe how REST has been used to guide the design and development of the architecture for the modern Web."

Answer (score 0):

The terms that apply generally here are

- web service
- client server

While the term REST is relevant, it becomes problematic because it has (at least) two different connotations:

The first, and what you are likely mean, is a web service which uses HTTP verbs (GET, PUT, POST) against a URI as part of it's interface.  Even within this, there are lots of debates around what is and isn't REST.

The term REST was coined by Roy Fielding in his famous [doctoral dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf) where he described the architecture of the web and why it was so successful.  The common usage of REST as described above gets it name from and is derived from a simplified notion of the architectural style in Fielding's dissertation. But, as you can see in the comments on your question, the particulars tend to generate debates that rarely produce much agreement.  Personally, I think those arguments are unlikely to be helpful to you and I would ignore that noise for now.  It's unfortunate that Fielding's term was commandeered in this way but that particular horse has left the barn.

TLDR; I think you are looking for something along the lines of ["RESTful Web Services"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/restful-web-services/9780596529260/).

Answer (score -1):

[It is called a Three Tier Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture)

Comment: How about a little more here?  A definition? An explanation of what 3 tier has to do with rest?

Comment: The existence of at a web API doesn't necessarily imply 3 tiers.